# aura:component support GA, PROTO, BETA

Tags: lightning-aura-components

A FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION is raised when i try to save my lightning component with "support" attribute.

In the following code, look at support attribute:

.cmp

```
<aura:component support="GA" >
</aura:component>
```

This exception is raised:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
>
> Failed to save undefined: 0Ad0Y000001BI9j:1,30: Invalid attribute
>   "support": Source

It is the same exception for PROTO, DEPRECATED, BETA and GA

If "support" attribute is not set, then aura docs shows "PROTO", and I don't find documentation about how to change the support level
http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [aura:component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_component.htm) doc, the `support` attribute is not available.

This attribute is only available in aura, but not in Lightning.
This means that so far there is no way to update this for our own Lightning Components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exists a way to remove PROTO flag in aura docs? Thx

Comment: No you can't, but in Winter '18 there is a new Component Library, so I guess it will replace auradocs at some point: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_library.htm